# NewRelic helm chart Installation

Tags: devops, newrelic, observability

We are trying to setup the open-sourced newrelic-infrastructure app locally in our machine in Kubernetes.Its giving the error message saying "It requires license key "

GitHub URL :https://github.com/newrelic/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/newrelic-infrastructure

Can someone confirm whether to bring up newrelic-infrastructure locally in our machine, do we need a license key from NewRelic ?. Is that open source newrelic is not free?

Error Message:

kube:##############################################################################
kube:####       ERROR: You did not set a licenseKey and/or cluster name.       ####
kube:##############################################################################
kube:
kube:This deployment will be incomplete until you set your New Relic license key and a cluster name.
kube:
kube:Then run:
kube:
kube:    helm upgrade newrelic-infrastructure 
kube:        --set licenseKey=YOUR-KEY-HERE 
kube:        --set cluster=YOUR-CLUSTER-NAME 
kube:        newrelic/newrelic-infrastructure

Comment: @GalloCedrone  :  Can you please help us on the above request .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We are trying to setup the open-sourced newrelic-infrastructure app locally in our machine in Kubernetes.Its giving the error message saying "It requires license key "

Answer (score 0):

Yeap you need a license key to start sending data to New Relic. The Infrastructure Agent (The code sending data to New Relic) is open source, but ingesting and processing data via New Relic does cost money.